# stock passwords outside document root

Tags: php, mysql, passwords, password-protection, document-root

In order to protect the passwords that I use to connect to mysql and to an smtp server, I thought of putting those passwords in a json file outside the document root and to run in the document root a json_decode();

Is this a safe solution? Or is it better to leave the passwords in a .php file somewhere in the document root?

thanks,

Comment: Or 3, place them in a php file outside the web root

Comment: or 3, correct. Is that how you do it ?

Comment: Well, in my projects, everything bar static assets (css, js, images) and a single entry point (index.php) are outside the web root. Really, providing your server is properly configured, its down to preference

Comment: The key point is to just make sure they're outside the document root - if you're coding in PHP it makes sense to use PHP files (probably defining a few constants).

Comment: or 4, use environment variables

Comment: Place all of this kind of private data in PHP constants in config/bootstrap files above the web root

Comment: @JimL good for portability as you can have your localhost dev variables separate to those on the server. I generally just save the path to the core config file as an environment variable and do it that way.